# What use is the future param in NDB's _post_delete_hook method?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

The signature for an NDB `_post_delete_hook` in GAE is:

`def _post_delete_hook(cls, key, future):`

I am wondering what benefit the `future` parameter gives. According to the docs on `Key.delete`, this `Future` will **always** be `None`. The docs even say you cannot use the `Future` to determine if a delete succeeded. Here they are (from `Key.delete` in `key.py`):

```
"""
This returns a Future, whose result becomes available once the
deletion is complete.  If no such entity exists, a Future is still
returned.  In all cases the Future's result is None (i.e. there is
no way to tell whether the entity existed or not).
"""
```

So, my question is, what use is this `future` parameter? Should I block on it to ensure an NDB delete is done before calling my delete hook? Or is it just a holdover/remnant from the `_post_delete_hook`'s initial implementation and the method now has to take 3 parameters no matter what?

It's a very open ended question, so I would just like to bolster my app engine knowledge and see what you guys have in mind/how you've used it in the past.

Comment: Where did you find that quote ? @hjc1710

Comment: That quote comes straight from NDB's source in `google/appengine/ext/ndb/key.py` in the docstring for NDB's delete_async (line 560). It might just be a remnant.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation [1]:

If you use post-hooks with asynchronous APIs, the hooks are triggered by calling `check_result()`, `get_result()` or yielding (inside a tasklet) an async method's future. Post hooks do not check whether the RPC was successful; the hook runs regardless of failure.

All post- hooks have a `Future` argument at the end of the call signature. This Future object holds the result of the action. You can call `get_result()` on this Future to retrieve the result; you can be sure that `get_result()` won't block, since the `Future` is complete by the time the hook is called.

For me, the arg `Future` this is just a remanent.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entity-models#using_model_hooks